# How to filter, SUM and display multiple values with multiple conditions added daily?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet that collects dozens of payments made daily through different means. For example, utilities bills, credit cards bills, personnel fees, expenses, etc. They are made in cash, by homebanking, by ATM, by check, and by courier. I managed to filter them daily with for example:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C3:C;D3:D="Homebanking";F3:F="november 10 2013"))
```

where it will show how much money was paid through homebanking on 11/10/2013.

**Column C** holds the values in $
**Column D** holds the means of payments values
**Column F** holds the dates (converted to `mmmm dd yyyy` because I couldn't get the formula to read 11/10/2013)

However, this method is taking too long because I need to add this formula daily for each item and each means of payment. I have been looking for a way automatically to generate a daily filter that displays how much has been paid on a daily basis for each item.

Is there a better way to sort through many dates and sum all values by day, item and means of payment?

EDIT: [SS with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah9a6PjQUxG_dHg4cUdzVE5UZVpQclFYMlpSNWtfa0E#gid=0)

It would be easier to work with filters, just as I would in Excel, but I'm thinking about filtering by date and then publish it as a web app, or at least as a web embedded chart.

Comment: Why don't you share some dummy info with us. The `QUERY` formula  will be best equipped to do the job.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Thanks for your reply, I've just added a SS with dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula would yield the most elegant presentation.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!A:C, "SELECT A, SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A PIVOT B")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

This is a good alternative, but formula wise a bit different.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!A:C, "SELECT A, B, SUM(C) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A, B   
   LABEL SUM(C) 'Costs'")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've added the results into your dummy sheet.

Comment: Just awesome! Both alternatives serve same purpose, and data is displayed elegantly! Thanks a lot!